# Why I get index out of range?

Tags: c#

So I have a List with 9 elements inside but I get an index oute of range error when I am trying to Add the array[4] element in the "right" List. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
public static int dosomething(ref List<int> array, int n) 
{
    List<int> left = new List<int>();
    List<int> right = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if (i < n/2) 
        {
            left.Add(array[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("Left[{0}] = {1}", i, left[i]);
        } 
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", i);
            right.Add(array[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("Right[{0}] = {1}", i, right[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get an answer here but it will not help you become a better developer. Learn how to debug. This is very essential.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, hit F11 over and over through the code

Comment: It's because `right` doesn't have an element at index `i`.

Comment: Unrelated: You don't need to pass `array` as `ref`.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Well that's hard to say because the snippet isn't a complete method. There may be more happening later

Comment: Is this because arrays are already references? thanks

Comment: Arrays are reference types, but the `ref` keyword can still be relevant. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx for an explanation and examples.

Comment: @BenAaronson You're right. I was just looking at the curlies. I see now that it doesn't return anything so it doesn't compile as it stands.

Comment: Yeah I need to change the array's elements so I think the ref is needed, right? Thanks again :)

Comment: @loukaspd, if you are just changing array elements you don't need to use ref; you only need to use ref if you want to replace what the array is pointing to. Read the link in a previous comment for a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong index for `left` and `right`. Since you're iterating through the array, and adding to `left` some of the time and `right` the rest of the time, you can't use `i` for the index into those to retrieve values. The error is actually happening in your `Console.WriteLine()` calls.

Instead, you can use:

```
left[left.Count - 1];
```

or:

```
right[right.Count - 1];
```

Comment: its better to hint (as comment) then to answer, answer like these are just not healthy!

Comment: Thanks! Just couldn't see it :P

Comment: @loukaspd You should mark this answer as accepted if it explained and fixed your problem by the way.